# List webservices in JBoss AS 4

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I have some applications deployed in JBoss Application Server 4.

I need to know how to get a list of deployed web services in that application server ?
Is there any informations in the jmx-console?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should see all deployed web services at: `http://localhost:8080/jbossws/services`.  Update IP and port information in that address accordingly.